# Can you add Dynamic fields in admin grid?

Tags: blocks, adminhtml, grid, tabs

I am trying to add Dynamic fields in admin gird. i am not using UI to do this.
I have added custom field using this

```
    $fieldset->addField(
        'test_field',
        'text',
        [
            'name'      => 'test_field',
            'label'     => __('Test field'),
            'title' => __('Test field'),
            'required' => true
        ]
    );
```